# AdMob ARMv7s support

Tags: ios, admob, armv7

Please note, though this question is tagged [armv7](/questions/tagged/armv7), it pertains to [armv7s](/questions/tagged/armv7s). The new tag could not be created.

I'm using the most up to date AdMob SDK (6.1.5) but it seems AdMob isn't yet built for armv7s

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GADBannerView", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libCompanyName.a(AdWhirlAdapterGoogleAdMobAds.o)

If somebody has had it working, can you explain your workaround?

Otherwise, does anybody know of any official documentation explaining when it will be updated.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to the question but apparently there is a way to hack up the libs to make it work with armv7s: http://www.galloway.me.uk/2012/09/hacking-up-an-armv7s-library/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update to Admob 6.2.0 or later.

See this post: http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/09/migrating-to-admob-v62-for-ios.html.

Also, include the AdSupport framework and remove the -all_load flag. 
You've got to use the -ObjC flag however.

Comment: This is a better answer as of 26th September.

Comment: I can confirm that Admob 6.2.0 properly supports armv7s

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for the libspotify sdk.. What I ended up doing is going to project/build settings/architectures and switching build active architecture only to Yes.

Comment: I have two xcodeprojs in this workspace and I had only set one of them to yes. I don't know if this will work on an actual device though.

Comment: Though it compiles and runs I don't think this solution will work on a device. It doesn't work on the iPhone 5 Simulator

Comment: Yea. This will work to at least build your product but as far as using it for production more research is required

Answer (score 1):

In the Target / Build Settings, the default values of Xcode 4.5 should show "Standard (armv7, armv7s)" for the Architecture settings.

Hover your mouse and click + to add a new entry:

"Any iOS SDK" => "armv7" //you need to type this manually.

This works for me when building the app on an iPhone 5 and as long as you include a Default-568h@2x.png file, it is enough to build a 4" iPhone 5 optimized UI.

I however ignore if you can submit a armv7 only build and that if Apple will treat it as an "iPhone 5" app.
I also ignore how much additional optimization would a proper armv7s compilation give you.

Answer (score 1):

add these frameworks:

AdSupport.framework
StoreKit.framework